# TextArea not working fine without a DIV tag

Tags: javascript, html, css, textarea

I have designed a simple modal box in HTML.

Now in the modal I tried creating 2 sections horizontally using a hr tag.It worked fine and sections were created.

After this I tried putting a text area in the upper section. I was able to successfully place the text area. However placing the text area there caused the seperator (hr tag line) to be moved further down.

However when I put the text area part of the code in a div element and provided a width and height it worked fine.

Please can anyone explain me the reason why it was not working without a div element.

Also if could be made to work without a DIV  tag , how is that possible ?

HTML Code :

```
<html>
    <link href="showTutorial.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

    <body >
    <script src="showTutorial.js" type="text/......script"></script>
        <div id="left1">
            <ol>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">What is ....</li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">What </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Strings</li>
                        </a>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Arrays</li>
                        </a>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Threads</li>
                        </a>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">What is ......</li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">What is ......</li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">Strings</li>
                                </a>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">Arrays</li>
                                </a>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">Threads</li>
                                </a>
                            </ol>
                        </div>
                        <div id="centre1">
                            <h1 id="centre1Label1">What is .....</h1>
                            <button id="myBtn">Open Modal</button>

                            <!-- The Modal -->
                            <div id="myModal" class="modal">

                                <!-- Modal content -->
                                <div class="modal-content">
                                    <span class="close">x</span>
                                    <div id="upperModal">
                                    <textarea id="textAreaId" rows="14">Hello</textarea> 
                                    </div>
                                    <hr id="seperator"/>
                                    <div>
                                    <p>Some text in below.</p>
                                    </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                            </div>
                            <div id="right1" >

                            </div>
                        </body>
                    </html>
```

JavaScript Code :

```
var modal,btn,span;

window.onload=function(){// Get the modal
modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

// Get the button that opens the modal
 btn = document.getElementById('myBtn');

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
 span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

 // When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
btn.onclick = function() {
 modal.style.display = "block";
}

span.onclick = function() {
 modal.style.display="none"; 
}

 }
```

CSS code :

```
#left1 { 
   width:170px;    
   background:#EDD8B3; 
   float:left;
   position:relative;
   top:180px; 
   left:5px;
   border: 3px solid grey;

   font-size: 1.2em;   
   padding:0;
   margin:0;

}
body
{
background-color:#EDD8B3;
margin:0;
padding:0;

}
#centre1 { 
   width:620px; 
   height:800px;
   left:10px;
   background:white; 
   float:left;
   position:relative;
   top:180px;
   box-shadow: 3px 3px grey;
   margin:0;
   padding-right: 450px;

   }
#right1 {   
margin:0;
padding:0; 
}
ol {
    list-style-type:none;
    background: #EDD8B3;
    padding-top:2px;
    margin-top:0.1px;

    }

ol li {
    border-bottom: 2px solid #f0f0f0;
    display:list-item;  
    padding:5px;
    margin-left:2px;
    margin-right:0.2px;
    margin-bottom:2px;  
    margin-top:10px;
}
ol li a {text-decoration:none;  
      color:#008080;
}

#centre1Label1{position:relative;left:480px;padding:0; margin-right:30px;}

.modal {
    display: none; /* Hidden by default */
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
    padding-top: 60px; /* Location of the box */
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 1300px; /* Full width */
    height: 1000px; /* Full height */
    overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */    
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content */
.modal-content {
    background-color: #fefefe;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #888;
    width: 1000px;
    height:450px;
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
    color: #aaaaaa;
    float: right;
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}                                                                               

#seperator{
margin-top:180px;
padding:0;
}

#textAreaId{
padding:0;
margin:0;
 min-width:100%;

 }

 #upperModal{
 height:50px;
 }
```

Comment: can you share you code on jsfiddle or codepen?

Comment: unless you share the code you are asking people to reverse engineer it based on your description which is a pretty big expectation. 

The first possible solution would be to disable bootstrap and see if that helps.

Comment: @PeterScott thanks for the suggestion. Added the code.

Comment: can you include the javascript and css include files as these will be important in diagnosing the problem - have you looked at any other related questions and answers such as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24584779/set-textarea-width-to-100-in-bootstrap-modal  Bootstrap does some fiddling with the DOM and I am guessing that this is causing your issues but with what you've posted people are not going to inclined to put too much effort into resolving the issue until they see more input from your efforts.

Comment: @PeterScott thanks. Added my javascript as well as css code.

Comment: ok cool - are you also able to add any external dependencies such as jquery or bootstrap? is this a homework question? Are you able to spawn off a fiddle from https://jsfiddle.net/pscott_au/5wLassmw/ and get to the point that works

Comment: I am a new in the field of html/javascript/css.  Was just trying to create a modal box on button click. Doing everything on a text editor. Did not get the external dependency part .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113916/discussion-between-peter-scott-and-professionallyme86).

Answer (score 0):

You have:

```
#seperator {
  margin-top: 180px;
  padding: 0;
}
```

That margin push `hr` down when you don`t have the 50px height of #upperModal.

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely clear on what you are asking however I have ported your code to JsFiddle ( https://jsfiddle.net/pscott_au/5wLassmw/ )

I cleaned up some of your mismatched hrefs and was able to get the 2 textareas without any problem .. https://jsfiddle.net/pscott_au/5wLassmw/7/

can you clarify what you are asking?

```
<!-- Modal content -->
                            <div class="modal-content">
                                <span class="close">x</span>
                                <div id="upperModal">
                                  <textarea id="textAreaId" rows=14>Hello</textarea> 
                                </div>
                                <hr id="seperator"/>

                                  <p>Some text in below.</p>
                                  <textarea id="textAreaId" rows=14>Hello</textarea> 

                                </div>
```